# How to insert more variable values into single column in a table?

Tags: mysql

```
v_fname='Hari';
v_lastname='Anil'

create table name_tab(fullname varchar(200));
```

how to insert `v_fname` and `v_lastname` into fullname column.

i tried like below not work out.

```
insert into name_tab(fullname) values('first name is :'||v_fname||'Last name is '||v_lastname);
```

Please help on this
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
insert into name_tab(fullname) 
select ws_concat("||","first name is:",v_fname, "Last name is:", v_lastname) 
from <other-table>;
```

The `<other-table>` is the table where your v_fname and v_lastname are stored.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
insert into name_tab(fullname) 
values( concat( 'First Name is : ', v_fname, ', Last Name is: ', v_lastname );
```

You have to use variable identifier like `$v_fname` and `$v_lastname` (this is PHP style) in the statement.

I suggest you to redefine the table structure to accommodate first_name and last_names as separate columns. So that you can store values from variables directly into respective columns.

**Example**:

```
v_fname='Hari';
v_lastname='Anil'

create table name_tab( first_name varchar(200), last_name varchar(200) );
```

Now you can prepare your insert statement as below:

```
insert into name_tab( first_name, last_name ) 
values( ?, ? );
```

Use prepared statement from you scripting language to set values for each of the parameters reading from variables.

Answer (score 0):

simple way is

```
$v_fname='Hari';
$v_lastname='Anil';
$v_fullname= 'first name is :' + $v_fname + ' Last name is ' + $v_lastname;

insert into name_tab(fullname) values('$v_fullname');
```

otherwise use update query like

```
update name_tab SET fullname=CONCAT('first name is :', '$v_fname', ' Last name is ', '$v_lastname');
```

i think it will also add a record...